# Database with 2 different table requirements

Tags: database, web2py

Sorry if the title is unclear, couldn't think of a good way to formulate it.
Currently I am checking if it has no parent in the view then shows it
I want to change this to the controller(Obviously)

My tables:

```
db.define_table('comments',
            Field('parent_id', 'reference comments', readable=False, writable=False),
            Field('body', 'text', label='Message', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            auth.signature)

db.define_table('comments_users',
            Field('user_id', 'reference auth_user', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('comments_id', 'reference comments', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('permission', 'integer', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()))
```

Select of what I want that doesn't work:

```
rows = db(
            (db.comments_users.user_id==auth.user.id) &
            (db.comments_users.comments_id.parent_id==0) # something like this is possible in view with a single row
        ).select(limitby=(0, 10))
```

I currently do it in the view which I want to change to the controller

```
{{for row in rows:}}
    {{if row.comments_id.parent_id==0:}}
        <td>{{=row.comments_id}}</td>
    {{pass}}
{{pass}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that `row.comments_id.parent_id` is a [recursive select](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Recursive-selects) -- for every row, it does a separate select, fetching the `db.comments` record identified by `row.comments_id`. This is inefficient when looping through all records, so not recommended.

The recursive select concept does not apply to queries, so you cannot do `db.comments_users.comments_id.parent_id == 0`, as you have in your query. However, you can do something similar to create a subquery:

```
no_parents = db.comments_users.comments_id.belongs(db.comments.parent_id == 0)
db((db.comments_users.user_id == auth.user_id) & no_parents).select(limitby(0, 10))
```

When apply the `belongs` method to a reference type field and pass in a query, a subquery is automatically generated. For more details, see the [belongs documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#belongs).

Note, instead of the subquery, it might be more efficient to do a join (you can check `db._timings` or use `response.toolbar()` to investigate):

```
db((db.comments_users.user_id == auth.user_id) &
   (db.comments.parent_id == 0) &
   (db.comments.id == db.comments_users.comments_id)).select(limitby(0, 10))
```

In that case, though, when looping through the rows, you will need to reference both the table name and the field name (e.g., `row.comments.id`, `row.comments_users.permission`, etc.), as each `Row` object will include fields from both tables.

Comment: Thank you very much
The problem I had before trying the join you had is that I forgot (db.comments.id == db.comments_users.comments_id)) which is just stupid on my side.